# MSBUILD Copy multiple files from source paths to different destination paths

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, xcopy

I need to copy the files from different source paths to different destination paths.

**Example Sources:**

- xyz\x.txt
- pqr\p.img

**Corresponding Destinations:**

- mno\x1.txt
- qst\p_sth.img

I am trying to use the batch copy as follows:

**Created a ItemGroup specifying source file and destination files:**
**Run batch Copy command:**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         DefaultTargets="start">

<ItemGroup>
        <src Include="xyz\x.txt">
            <OutputFile>"mno\x1.txt"</OutputFile>
        </src>
        <src Include="pqr\p.img" >
            <OutputFile>"qst\p_sth.img"</OutputFile>
        </src>
</ItemGroup>

 <Target Name="start">


    <Message Importance="high" Text="Bulk Copy"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(src.FullPath)" DestinationFiles="%(src.OutputFile)"/>
  </Target>
  </Project>
```

I am getting the "Illegal character" error pointing to line #17, shown as:

[image: MSBuild Error]
Can I even achieve this using Copy command? Also RoboCopy command is acceptable.

*[But, requirement is we need full source path with file name and full destination path with file name]*

What is the best approach to handle this?

Comment: That copy looks fine, please specify what doesn't work?

Comment: @stijn I am getting illegal character error. FYI, I have edited the post with current script file and attached the error snapshot.

Comment: Just get rid of the quotes around the 2 OutputFile items?

Comment: thank you @stijn ... it was such a blunder and I completely overlooked the error message ... (I was only concentrating on the command side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is just removing the unrequired quotes from the output file paths (As suggested by @stjin):

```
<ItemGroup>
        <src Include="xyz\x.txt">
            <OutputFile>mno\x1.txt</OutputFile>
        </src>
        <src Include="pqr\p.img" >
            <OutputFile>qst\p_sth.img</OutputFile>
        </src>
</ItemGroup>
```